# Statistical tests for one independent variable and dependent variable without any levels

Tags: anova, t-test

I am doing a research paper project on personality and social media.

My research question is:
Does having a certain Big Five personality trait predict how much time is spent on social media? Gender as a moderator.

I have made a survey on Qualtrics website. It asks about what personality type you are from the Myer-Briggs assessment and what percentile you are on the Big Five personality traits (Open-mindedness, conscientiousness, extraversion, agreeableness, and Negative Emotionality). This percentile is written as text entry. Later it talks about time spent on social media sites such as Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, Snapchat, Reddit, and TikTok: 0-2 hours, 2-4 hours, 4-6 hours, 8+ hours, and not applicable.

I need help with the results portion of my paper. I am confused to which statistical test I need to do.

Should I do like for each Big Five personality type vs each social media time spent on. Are there five levels of personality type (independent variable) [OCEAN]? And five levels of time spent on social media?

I got to SPSS output but got overwhelmed to what tests to perform. Then I checked out Excel with my data. I need some graphs and tables, and p values if possible.

Thank you in advance,
Nisha

My survey Qs:

1. What was your personality type on the Myers-Briggs survey from the website: https://www.16personalities.com/free-personality-test ?

   - Inspector (ISTJ)
   - Crafter (ISTP)
   - Protector (ISFJ)
   - Artist (ISFP)
   - Advocate (INFJ)
   - Mediator (INFP)
   - Architect (INTJ)
   - Thinker (INTP)
   - Persuader (ESTP)
   - Director (ESTJ)
   - Performer (ESFP)
   - Caregiver (ENFJ)
   - Champion (ENFP)
   - Giver (ENFJ)
   - Debater (ENTP)
   - Commander (ENTJ)
2. What was your scored percentile for Open-mindedness on the Big Five survey from the Open- website: https://www.outofservice.com/bigfive/ ?
3. What was your scored percentile for Conscientiousness on the Big Five survey from the website: https://www.outofservice.com/bigfive/ ?
4. What was your scored percentile for Extraversion on the Big Five survey from the website: https://www.outofservice.com/bigfive/ ?
5. What was your scored percentile for Agreeableness on the Big Five survey from the website: https://www.outofservice.com/bigfive/ ?
6. What was your scored percentile for Negative Emotionality on the Big Five survey from the website: https://www.outofservice.com/bigfive/ ?
7. What social media accounts do you own or use? (select all that apply)

   - Facebook
   - Twitter
   - Instagram
   - Snapchat
   - Reddit
   - TikTok
8. Which social media site do you most frequently use?

   - Facebook
   - Twitter
   - Instagram
   - Snapchat
   - Reddit
   - TikTok
9. What social media activities do you engage in? (select all that apply)

   - Uploading photos or videos of yourself
   - Updating your status
   - Managing your profile
   - Commenting on other people's status updates, photos, or videos
   - Chatting online with other people
   - Sharing views or opinions on worldly issues and current events
   - Connecting with experts in your field
   - Promoting research
   - Finding or distributing information
   - Following celebrities or other famous people
   - Making fan pages
   - Advertising products
10. What is the total number of friends you have on Facebook?
11. What is the total number of followers you have on Twitter?
12. How many accounts do you follow on Twitter?
13. What is the total number of followers you have on Instagram?
14. How many accounts do you follow on Instagram?
15. What type of content do you find interesting on social media? (select all that apply)

    - Sports
    - Food
    - Entertainment (movies, TV shows, etc.)
    - Music
    - Humor
    - Messages (inspirational, motivational, etc.)
    - Politics
    - Photos or videos (friends, family members, others)
    - Nature/landscape
    - Animals
    - Fashion
16. With respect to Facebook, do you usually click 'like' more than comment on other people's statuses?

    - True
    - False
    - Not applicable
17. With respect to Twitter, do you usually click 'like' more than comment on other people's statuses?

    - True
    - False
    - Not applicable
18. With respect to Instagram, do you usually click 'like' more than comment on other people's statuses?

    - True
    - False
    - Not applicable
19. If applicable, how many hours a week do you spend on Facebook? Estimate if 'screen time' data is unaccessible.

    - 0-2 hours
    - 2-4 hours
    - 4-6 hours
    - 8+ hours
    - Not applicable
20. If applicable, how many hours a week do you spend on Twitter? Estimate if 'screen time' data is unaccessible.

    - 0-2 hours
    - 2-4 hours
    - 4-6 hours
    - 8+ hours
    - Not applicable
21. If applicable, how many hours a week do you spend on Instagram? Estimate if 'screen time' data is unaccessible.

    - 0-2 hours
    - 2-4 hours
    - 4-6 hours
    - 8+ hours
    - Not applicable
22. If applicable, how many hours a week do you spend on Snapchat? Estimate if 'screen time' data is unaccessible.

    - 0-2 hours
    - 2-4 hours
    - 4-6 hours
    - 8+ hours
    - Not applicable
23. If applicable, how many hours a week do you spend on Reddit? Estimate if 'screen time' data is unaccessible.

    - 0-2 hours
    - 2-4 hours
    - 4-6 hours
    - 8+ hours
    - Not applicable
24. If applicable, how many hours a week do you spend on TikTok? Estimate if 'screen time' data is unaccessible.

    - 0-2 hours
    - 2-4 hours
    - 4-6 hours
    - 8+ hours
    - Not applicable

THE SCREEN TIME QUESTIONS ARE RELATED TO TIME SPENT ON SOCIAL MEDIA.

Comment: Should I do t-test or ANOVA or something else?

Comment: How would you do a t-test or ANOVA?

Comment: I have no clue. I guess I would not be using t-tests because you need two groups to compare. And in ANOVA, you need some levels of both independent and dependent variables. I wish I could show you a copy of my survey questions. Is there a way I can upload it on this website?

Comment: You can type them out or post a photo.

Comment: @Dave I typed up my survey questions. You can take a look.

Comment: I was thinking of looking at each Big Five personality trait (open-mindedness, conscientiousness, extraversion, agreeableness, and negative emotionality) and then add each participant's total hours of social media activity. For example, a person with a score percentile of 63 will have time spent = 12-14 hours (range because my answer choices was in range). This person was on the low end of open-mindedness. A person with a score percentile of 95 will have spent = 18-22 hours. This person was on the high end of open-mindedness. See some trends.

Comment: The higher the level of open-mindedness, the more time is spent on social media. Or something of that nature. Does that make sense? I'll skip with graph or tables. Our professor said only use them if it relates to your study. This is an easy type class, not so complicated.

Comment: This seems a request not for an answer to a focused question but for someone to act as coach or consultant.